# is there any way to instead of using a keyboard key, use a button on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a script to count, like in a queue.
it curreltly is using a keyboard key (right arrow) to skip the numbers but i would like it to use a button on screen to do so.
can someone pls help, im new in programing, all the help is much apreciated :)

my code:

```
   <script>
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("body").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var senhaAtual   = $("#senhaAtualNumero");
        var senhaNormal  = $("#senhaNormal");
        var senhaPrior   = $("#senhaPrioridade");
        var ultimaSenha  = $("#ultimaSenhaNumero");
        var audioChamada = $("#audioChamada");

        if(e.keyCode == 39){

            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");

        }
        if(e.keyCode == 65){
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 83){
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you wan't button to do the same as pressing the arrow key ?

Comment: yes it's basically it

Answer (score 2):

You can make a button, handle its "click" event and then make it run the same code as is run when the user presses the right arrow key. To avoid duplication or repetition, that code can be placed into a separate function, so it can be called from both event handlers.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var senhaAtual   = $("#senhaAtualNumero");
   var senhaNormal  = $("#senhaNormal");
   var senhaPrior   = $("#senhaPrioridade");
   var ultimaSenha  = $("#ultimaSenhaNumero");
   var audioChamada = $("#audioChamada");

    $("body").on('keydown', function(e) {

        if(e.keyCode == 39){
            right();
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 65){
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 83){
            senha = parseInt(senhaPrior.val().replace("P","")) - 1;
            senhaAtual.html("P" + pad(senha, 3));
            senhaPrior.val("P" + pad(senha, 3));
        }
    });

    $("#rightButton").click(right);

    function right()
    {
            ultimaSenha.html(senhaAtual.html());
            senha = parseInt(senhaNormal.val()) + 1;
            senhaAtual.html(pad(senha, 4));
            senhaNormal.val(pad(senha, 4));
            audioChamada.trigger("play");
    }
});
```

You may wish to do the same for the other keys, if you are planning to have a button for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<button>` tag and a .onclick function. 
See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_pushbutton.asp)

```js
var page = 0;
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() { 
    /// you code here
    page++; console.log(page) // this is an example
}
```

```html
<button id="foo"> press me </button>
```

For the right arrow it would be:

```
       document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() { right(); }
       /// this goes into your script file
```

And this goes in your html file:
`<button id="foo"> Next page </button>`

Comment: i found the code in the internet, i am trying to adapt it to my project XD

Comment: ok i dont know if i got it, what exactly should i put on the "/// you code here"?

Comment: what key you wan't to simulate pressing the button ?

Comment: i am sorry, i dont know if i am doing it wrong, probably i am, but it is not working :(